# How to integrate Zoho analytics with Jupyter notebook?

Tags: dataset, data-analysis, python-3.x, tools, pip

I am trying to connect Zoho Analytics and Python for importing data from Zoho Analytics.
I have already installed `!pip install zoho-analytics-connector`. What should I do next?

I am new to integrating with other BI tools so unable to find out a better solution. Can you guide me on this?
I am referring the instructions from https://pypi.org/project/zoho-analytics-connector/ and https://www.zoho.com/analytics/api/#python-library.

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from ReportClient import ReportClient
import sys
```

Now, I am getting an error as:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3444, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21424/2162254720.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ReportClient import ReportClient

  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\ReportClient.py", line 108
    except Exception,inst:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```
````